# SSD Asserted Errors, Dell server

Tags: ssd, ipmitool

I have installed Crucial SSDs on a new Dell r620 server.  Ipmitool keeps alerting that the drives state is changing.

```
/etc/cron.hourly/ipmisel.cron:

   2 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa3 | Drive Fault | Asserted
   3 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa5 | Drive Fault | Asserted
   4 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa7 | Drive Fault | Asserted
   5 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa2 | Drive Fault | Asserted
   6 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa4 | Drive Fault | Asserted
   7 | 03/07/2013 | 23:32:18 | Drive Slot #0xa6 | Drive Fault | Asserted
```

The RAID and drives however appear to be functioning fine.

Comment: I doubt that drive is on the HCL for the PERC RAID controllers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring will continue to complain, because it's not a Dell drive.  Dell puts special firmware on their drives to support some of the monitoring.

Since it's not a Dell approved drive, you likely won't get any warranty support if anything goes wrong.  Whether that matters is up to you.  The monitoring of the drive will likely never work properly, so you may also not get alerted about potential drive failures until it's too late.

[This blog post](http://www.modelcar.hk/?p=5933) has quite a few details on using crucial SSDs in Dell servers, including the error you are getting, the relevant part being:

> The issue is that these drives do not have the Dell firmware on them to properly
> communicate with the Perc Controllers. The controllers are not getting the messages
> they are expecting from these drives and thus throws the error.
>
> You really won’t get around this issue until Dell releases support for these drives
> and at this time there does not appear to be any move towards doing this.
>
> I was able to clear all the logs under Server Administrator.  The individual lights
> on the drives still blink amber but the main console stays blue.  It will go back to > amber after a reboot for any reason but clearing the logs again put it back to blue.  Minor annoyance for great performance.

Comment: Thank you, this helps clarify the issue.  I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for the reminder.  I am a  bit new to the ServerFault scene.